# Row selection with multiple p:dataTable

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

In the following scenario, where I have several dataTables that I build iterating over a ui:repeat tag, I have experienced that  row listener returns null for selected elements that are not in the first table.

In order to understand the model object, I have several menus, and each of them contains several areas.

Any help will be much appreciated.

xhtml below:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{someBean.menus}" var="menu">                

    <p:dataTable var="area" value="#{menu.areas}"
        rowKey="#{area.id}" selection="#{menu.area}" selectionMode="single">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{someBean.rowSelected}" />

        <f:facet name="header">#{menu.name}</f:facet>

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{area.id}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">Area name</f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{area.name}" />  
        </p:column>  

    </p:dataTable>

</ui:repeat>
```

ListDataModel java implementation:

```
public class Areas extends ListDataModel<Area> implements SelectableDataModel<Area>, Serializable {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9102592194300556930L;

    public Areas() {
    }

    public Areas(List<Area> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Area getRowData(String rowKey) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Area> areas = (List<Area>)getWrappedData();        
        for (Area area : areas) {
            if (String.valueOf(area.getId()).equals(rowKey)) {
                return area;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Area area) {
        return area.getId();
    }

}



public class Menus extends ListDataModel<Menu> implements SelectableDataModel<Menu>, Serializable {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4079772686830676202L;

    public Menus() {
    }

    public Menus(List<Menu> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Menu getRowData(String rowKey) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Menu> menus = (List<Menu>)getWrappedData();        
        for (Menu menu : menus) {
            if (String.valueOf(menu.getId()).equals(rowKey)) {
                return menu;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Menu menu) {
        return menu.getId();
    }

}
```

...in the bean someBean

```
public void rowSelected(SelectEvent event) {
    Area selectedArea = (Area)event.getObject(); //This, is null for other tables except the first
    System.out.println("SELECTED AREA:" + selectedArea);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to show you the solution: replace ui:repeat with another p:dataTable !!!

```
<p:dataTable value="#{someBean.menus}" var="menu">

    <p:column>                  

        <p:dataTable var="area" value="#{menu.areas}"
          rowKey="#{area.id}" selection="#{menu.area}" selectionMode="single">

          <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{someBean.rowSelected}" />

          <f:facet name="header">#{menu.name}</f:facet>

          <p:column>  
             <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>  
             <h:outputText value="#{area.id}" />  
          </p:column>  

          <p:column>  
             <f:facet name="header">Area name</f:facet>  
             <h:outputText value="#{area.name}" />  
          </p:column>  

       </p:dataTable>

    </column>

</p:dataTable>
```